# Unable to play audio / speech from iOS Swift Safari Extension on device (OSStatus error 2003329396)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, safari-extension, avspeechsynthesizer

I'm currently trying to use `AVSpeechSynthesizer` to speak text from within an iOS Safari extension:

```swift
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
...

let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: self.text)
utterance.rate = 0.55;
self.synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

**On a simulator this works fine. However, on a physical device, I get the following error (even when the device is unmuted/volume-up):**

```
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002
[AXTTSCommon] Failure starting audio queue alp!
[AXTTSCommon] Run loop timed out waiting for free audio buffer
[AXTTSCommon] _BeginSpeaking: speech cancelled error: Error Domain=TTSErrorDomain Code=-4001 "(null)"
[AXTTSCommon] _BeginSpeaking: couldn't begin playback
```

I have looked through quite a few SO and Apple Dev Forums threads and have tried many of the proposed solutions with no luck. Here are the things I've tried:

1. Linking `AVFAudio.framework` and `AVFoundation.framework` to the extension.
2. Starting an `AVAudioSession` prior to playing the utterance:

```swift
do {
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try session.setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
    try session.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
} catch let error {
    print("Error starting audio: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

This actually results in another error being thrown right before the same errors above:

```
Error starting audio: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003329396.)
```

3. Playing a plain `mp3` audio file:

```swift
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample", withExtension: "mp3") else {
    print("Couldn't find file")
    return
}

do {
    self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    self.player.play()
    print("**playing sound")
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error playing sound: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

This prints the following:

```
**playing sound
[aqsrv]              AQServer.cpp:72    Exception caught in AudioQueueInternalNotifyRunning - error -66671
```

4. Enabling `Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture` in Background Modes for the main target app (not available for the extension).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

The solution below gets rejected due to a validation error when submitting to App Store Connect.

I filed a Technical Support Incident with Apple, and this was their response:

> Safari extensions are very short-lived, hence not fit for audio playback or speech synthesis. Not being able to validate an app extension in Xcode with a manually-added plist entry for background audio is the designed behavior. The general recommendation is to synthesize speech using JavaScript in conjunction with the Web Speech API.

TLDR: Use the [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) for text-to-speech in Safari extensions, not `AVSpeechSynthesizer`.

---

**Original answer:**

Adding the following to the **extension's** `Info.plist` allowed the audio to play as expected:

```
<dict>
    ...
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
    </array>
    ...
</dict>
```

Interestingly, it actually shows the same errors in the console as before, but it does play the audio.